# How to stop scrolling when the Custom view has touchlisteners in android?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I am dynamically adding an Custom Views to the relative layouts.

In my custom View,I have an Child view which can be dragged left and right.Its all working fine with only one view in the Relative layout.But when there are multiple views  ACTION_UP events are not called for the dragging child views. so, I want to stop the scrolling when user touches the Dragging childView.

Main xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        tools:context=".MainActivity" >


            <com.example.dynamicscroll.ObservableScrollView
            android:id="@+id/mainScrollView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


        <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent">   

         <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                />

      </HorizontalScrollView>
      </com.example.dynamicscroll.ObservableScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

inflatedfeedmodebloops.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="#ababab"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/transparent"
     >  


  <com.example.dynamicscroll.ConstrainedDragAndDropView
            android:id="@+id/dndView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    >     

        <ImageView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/like_small"
            android:id="@+id/dummy"
            android:visibility="gone"

           />  

     <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

        android:id="@+id/images">

         <!-- left circle  -->
      <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical"

           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"


          android:id="@+id/half_left">


      <ImageView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/like_small"
            android:id="@+id/like_image"

           />  

      <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/like_image"
            android:text="36"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="#DF013A"
            android:id="@+id/likes_count"

            />

     </RelativeLayout>
      <!-- end of left circle  -->
   <!--   <ImageView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_1"
            android:background="@drawable/pinkcircle"
            android:id="@+id/full_left"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:visibility="gone"

            />
         -->
     <!-- right circle  -->
     <ImageView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

            android:id="@+id/backbtn"

            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

       <!-- end of right circle  -->

       <!-- cartoon image  -->

       <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"           ----->I want to drag this image,so I want to stop
                                                      scrolling when user touches this view.           

         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/img_1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/cartoon_image"> 

       <ImageView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/like_small"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/ivheart"
            android:visibility="gone"
           />    

      <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/play_btn"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/play_btn"
           >


           </RelativeLayout>
      </RelativeLayout> 

       <!-- end of cartoon image  --> 

     </RelativeLayout>

     </com.example.dynamicscroll.ConstrainedDragAndDropView>  



   </RelativeLayout>  

</LinearLayout>
```

For adding Views to Relative Layout:

```
 for(int i=0;i<al_new.size();i++)
      {

                Log.e("inflating the bloops ","....................");
                final View view= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.inflatedfeedmodebloops, null);

       iv=  (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.main_img);
       ivLike=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.like_image);
       txtlikesCount=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.likes_count);
     loader.DisplayImage(al_new.get(i).replace(" ", "%20"), iv);
      ConstrainedDragAndDropView dndView = (ConstrainedDragAndDropView)view.findViewById(R.id.dndView);
            dndView.setDragHandle(view.findViewById(R.id.cartoon_image),view.findViewById(R.id.half_left),heart);
            dndView.setAllowVerticalDrag(false,ScrollingFeedmode.this); 
      rl.addView(view);




 if (view.findViewById(R.id.cartoon_image)!= null && myscrollview!= null) {

            view.findViewById(R.id.cartoon_image).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                                    mainScrollView.getParent()
                                            .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                            return false;
                                }
                        });

}

          }
```

So,can anyone suggest me how can I stop scrolling when user touches the childview.

Answer (score 0):

**Use the following code to stopping parent view scrolling while touching childview**

```
if (childView != null && parentView != null) {

            childView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                                    findViewById(R.id.parent_view).getParent()
                                            .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                            return false;
                                }
                        });

}
```

Comment: It didnt worked for me,please see my edited question.I have also added my main xml.

Comment: Really difficult to understand your question.. pls kindly edit your question and share code for adding view(adapter) to child.